# iOS Progressive Web App Dark Mode Startup Image?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to create a dark mode option for the apple-touch-startup-image (splash screen) of my iOS PWA that if dark mode is on, then it will replace all of the links for the apple-touch-startup-images to a dark mode for my users.

I have thought about that since dark mode works with the css:

```
@media(prefers-color-scheme: dark){ ... }
```

then it could easily replace them.

I created this javascript, but it didn't seem to work:

```
var darksplash = window.matchMedia( "(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" );
if (darksplash.matches) {document.querySelector('link[rel="apple-touch-startup-image"]').setAttribute("href", "assets/images/splashscreens/dark.png");}
```

Any ideas? I was thinking it could be an error in the javascript code, i'm not the best at JavaScript.

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add another apple-touch-startup-image under each one with "(prefers-color-scheme: dark) and " at the at the beginning of the media=""

Found at:
https://github.com/onderceylan/pwa-asset-generator/issues/51

Answer (score 0):

I do't know much about css or javascript,but I will try run JavaScript code in web console if I injected code not work.

1. Opening your website in chorme,right click and click  **Inspect**
2. There is an option at the top of the box, select console.
3. run your JavaScript code.

If that's works, it may the timing of your injection of the JavaScript code is not so appropriate,or your error in javascript code.